# SMS in QR Code?

Tags: qr-code

According to [this page](https://www.unitag.io/qrcode/what-are-the-different-types-of-qrcodes) an SMS is possible to get in a QR Code. I'm creating a generator but have no idea how they do it in their one. The scanner I'm using to test the codes brings theirs up with two fields, "to" and "body".

What information do you need to put in the qr code? For example, for the emails you require the mailto syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things  you can try:

`smsto:+447700900888`

[image]

Or,

`sms:+447700900888`

[image]

Where `+44` is the country code.  Remember to URL encode the `+` as `%2B`.

Both should work on the majority of modern smartphones - but remember to double check using the phones your customers actually have.

Comment: How would you add text to this? I gather it's the same as mailto?

    `?body=SMS Message`

Comment: That's right - but not every phone / QR scanner supports ?body - in particular, I think the iPhone has a problem with it.

Comment: Actually sms:+123456 is the preferred way to do this: see this almost unique QR Code data draft https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents, and the SMS URI RFC http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5724. I have to say that https://www.unitag.io does use sms:+123456:MessageText but using sms:+123456?body=MessageText is a more standard way.